# Netty: Getting current 'Channel' in random place

Tags: java, netty

I know that when I handle request from client new 'Channel' is initialized.

When I have available 'ChannelHandlerContext' reference, obviously I can retrieve 'Channel' and 'Pipeline'.

But, if I understand right, when I lose access to such reference in my code I have no way to retrieve current channel.

Is this right? Is there some way to dig it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right... You will have to store the reference somewhere and access it if needed.